Some problems using maps in Isabelle/HOL
Two questions about mappings:
[1] This lemma is trivial
lemma [simp] : "(m(x ↦ v))|` {x} = [x ↦ v]"

but how can I prove these two lemmas?
lemma : "(m(x ↦ v))|`(dom(m) - {x}) = m"

lemma : "m ⊆ m m(k ↦ v')"

[2] I have defined the set of all mappings between characters and elements of a generic type as follows:
function allMaps :: "char set ⇒ 'a set ⇒ (char ⇀ 'a ) set" where
"(card keys) = 0  ⟹ allMaps keys values = {Map.empty}" |
"((card keys) > 0) ∧ ((card values) = 0) ⟹ allMaps keys values = {}" |
"((card keys) > 0) ∧ ((card values) > 0) ⟹ allMaps keys values =
 (let
    k = SOME x. x ∈ keys
     in ({m(k ↦ v) | m v. v ∈ values ∧ m ∈ allMaps (keys - {k}) values})
)"

But I am not able to prove this lemma. Any help?
lemma allMapsLemma :
fixes vals :: "'a set" and keys :: "char set" and x :: "char"
assumes "(card vals) > 0" and "x ∉ keys"
shows "(allMaps (keys ∪ {x}) vals) = {
 m(x ↦ v) | m v. v ∈ vals ∧ m ∈ (allMaps keys vals) }"


I already see... But how can I use inductive predicates to deal with allMaps? Don't I have the same problem even if I use an inductive predicate?

lemma : "(m(x ↦ v))|`(dom(m) - {x}) = m"

Try nitpick as the theorem does not hold.
lemma : "m ⊆ m m(k ↦ v')"

Does not even type in Isabelle.
allMaps

The choice operator (SOME) does not mean that you can pick the element. It means that someone else (technically, the model you are in) is picking it. You will get the same every time actually (within one Isabelle session). Think of it, as someone else is picking it and can change each time you are restarting Isabelle. Your proof will only work if they are independent of the object.
For real non-determinism, you need inductive predicates.
